# Setting element attributes from an array

Tags: jquery

**jQuery:**

```
var numbers= ["4", "5"];
for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { 
    var rirs = $(".rirs")
    $(rirs).attr("pl", numbers[i])
}
```

This only sets the last element in the array which is 5.  such as `<div class="rirs" pl="5"> </div>` for both divs.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="rirs"></div>
<div class="rirs"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)** method like following.

```
var numbers= ["4", "5"];
var rirs = $(".rirs");
for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {         
    rirs.eq(i).attr("pl", numbers[i])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the index of the div you are selecting, with ":eq()" selector

Try:

```
var numbers= ["4", "5"];
for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { 
 var rirs = $(".rirs:eq("+i+")")
 rirs.attr("pl", numbers[i])
}
```